# jQuery Mobile dynamic input range - slide events not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-on

I cannot figure out why my slide events are not working on a range input type in jQuery Mobile. I have the following piece of code to dynamically build my input (slider):

```
var $label = $('<label for="slider1">Slider: </label>'),
    $slider = $('<input id="slider1" name="slider1" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1">');

$('#mainContent').append($label, $slider).trigger('create');

$slider.on('slidestart', function (e) {
        console.log('slidestart');
    })
    .on('slidestop', function (e) {
        console.log('slidestop');
    });
```

Yet these events are never fired and nothing is ever logged - even if I do something like an `alert('')` in the function, no alert pops up. Everything renders fine, just the events are not binding - any idea why?

A live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/y4Y9L/.

Comment: Sridhar's answer is right, but he doesn't say why. jQuery Mobile actually clones your `<input>` element when it augments it with its slider widget. The original element stored in `$slider` is not part of the DOM anymore, you have to re-match its clone instead.

Comment: Awesome - never knew that. Even when looking at the DOM, it looked identical to how I had set it up so was clueless as to why. But, this explains it perfectly. I guess the next step would have been the jQuery code, as fun as that would have been!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#slider1').on('slidestart', function (e) {
    console.log('slidestart');
}).on('slidestop', function (e) {
    console.log('slidestop');
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Y9L/1/)

Comment: Nope, `$slider` does not hold the element's HTML. It's a jQuery object holding the element itself, the problem is that it's the "wrong" element.

Comment: Thank you guys! That's a huge help. I've been scratching my head for ages why that wouldn't work!